# Enhanced domain affect on OAuth token and Rest API calls

Tags: oauth2, enhanced-domains

We have Salesforce app registration and a bunch of customers OAuth2 Access/Refresh tokens stored in our Db.

The questions are:

1. Does enhanced domain affect 'instance_url' property of the token and will it be updated?
2. We use 'instance_url' for REST API calls. Will it be affected by enhanced domain name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calling REST APIs based on `instance_url` from oAuth response should always work no matter what domain strategy is in place.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce documents all of the considerations you should take in the article below.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced_considerations.htm&type=5

Reading through it, you will see that the OAuth 2.0 URL does not change, so your `instance_url` will remain unchanged.

The only URL that gets affected will be the experience cloud URL or public site URL

Comment: I've also noted that sandbox SSO integrations may (will) break from the IdP

Comment: Yes sandbox urls will change and not the production urls except for site and experience cloud urls.